# Mechanism of elimination of trans-dibromocyclooctane

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I recently did this reaction according to a protocol:

[image]

And although the product formation was monitored via NMR and IR techniques, I am unable to comprehend how the product **3** was formed. It should be an elimination reaction, however, the bromines are located in a *trans* fashion, so the usual reaction path for an E2 elimination (antiperiplanar hydrogen) is not given. How can this elimination happen then?

Comment: Syn eliminations do occur as in endo- or exo-2-bromo-[2.2.1]-bicycloheptane.